# Setting up RAID on Debian - mdstat has no personalities

Tags: linux, debian, raid

I'm reading up on setting up a RAID with two drives on my Debian install, and that the `/proc/mdstat` file contains a list of the supported raid types by the kernel next to 'Personalities'. Running `cat /proc/mdstat` however shows only blank space where the supported RAID types should be. I'm running Debian Testing. Does my kernel really not support any RAID types or am I missing something here? Thanks.

Here's the full output of the cat, just in case someone needs it:

```
cat /proc/mdstat

Personalities : 
unused devices: <none>
```

My kernel version is `4.16.0-2-amd64`

Answer (score 0):

I have a RAID array set up on a Raspberry PI (don't ask why), but when I run

```
cat /proc/mdstat
```

it prints

```
Personalities : [raid0] 
md0 : active raid0 my_raid_devices
      num_of blocks super 1.2 512k chunks
```

The my_raid_devices and num_of refer to the RAID devices I'm using and number of blocks available respectively; but when I read the same file on another system it reads

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
unused devices:
```

This system has no RAID arrays set up, but notice the Personalities differences. I believe this has to do with kernel differences as well; the Pi is running kernel 4.14.34, while the other system is running 4.9.0-3. They are both running Debian (Raspbian for the Pi, of course).

Post your kernel release, by doing

```
uname -r
```

It doesn't matter if you are administrator or not.

EDIT: Can you attempt to build a array even with this issue? If not, maybe try downgrading to a different kernel?

Comment: I've edited my version into the question

Comment: Also I'm actually very curious as to why you have RAID configured on a Pi.

Comment: Extra storage, because I happened to have a bunch of flash drives lying around and I needed a small network-accessible storage system

Answer (score 0):

The kernel modules providing the MD raid services are only loaded when needed. /proc/mdstat reflects what is available at the current point in time.

You can force the loading of the raid modules:

```
sudo modprobe raid0
sudo modprobe raid1
sudo modprobe raid456
sudo modprobe raid10
sudo modprobe linear
```

After doing that /proc/mdstat will show all these raid methods.

In normal use the kernel automatically loads the necessary modules, so you won't need to manually modprobe these.